# How to implement a payment gateway from credit card to bitcoins

Tags: web-services, payment-gateway, credit-card, bitcoin

I am looking for an API to allow customers to pay a service in bitcoins by inputting their credit card number or via bank transfer. Ideally the gateway would buy the bitcoins with the credit card and deposit them on a provided bitcoin wallet address.

I found some services like https://cex.io, but their api (https://cex.io/rest-api#place-instant-order) is not offering the payment through credit card option. 
Any idea what would be the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The https://cex.io IS the solution.  However, the customer would have to spend the bitcoin - you cannot take a credit card, convert it Bitcoin and pay yourself.  In essence you want to create a cash transaction from a credit card.  Not possible I believe - nor legal possibly.  The Bitcoin would have to go to the customer's wallet, and then THEY would need to send it to another Bitcoin address